# Radoop: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: hadoop, hive, rapidminer

I have installed Rapidminer , Radoop , Hadoop and Hive for Single node cluster and performed Radoop Connection and got error like this.

```
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:27 AM]: Connection test for 'Kanni' started.
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:27 AM]: Using Radoop version 7.3.0.
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:27 AM]: Running tests: [Hive connection, Fetch dynamic settings, Java version, HDFS, MapReduce, Radoop temporary directory, MapReduce staging directory, Spark assembly jar existence, UDF jar upload, Create permanent UDFs]
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:27 AM]: Running test 1/10: Hive connection
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:27 AM]: Hive server 2 connection (localhost:10000) test started.
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:28 AM] SEVERE: Test failed: Hive connection
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:28 AM]: Cleaning after test: Hive connection
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:28 AM]: Total time: 1.031s
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:28 AM] SEVERE: java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:28 AM] SEVERE: Hive server 2 connection test failed. Please check that the server/daemon runs and is accessible on the address and port you specified.
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:28 AM] SEVERE: Test failed: Hive connection
[Jan 28, 2017 12:28:28 AM] SEVERE: Connection test for 'Kanni' failed.
```

can anyone help me tpo get rid of this problem!

Comment: This is because hive is not able to connect to namenode - make sure all hadoop services are up and running. (command `jps`)

Comment: Can you provide any more information? It seems very relevant to at least include to include the command that produced this output.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Ports which are necessary to be opend for the connection between Radoop and RapidMiner. (NameNode, DataNode ...)

Is Hadoop running on the same system as RapidMiner or in a Cloud like Azure?
Can you as well share your logs with us so we can have a closer look?